# Род имён собственных на иностранном языке

Tags: грамотная-речь, ономастика, заимствования, английский-язык

*Если кандидат владеет Excel, ему следует привести примеры задач, которые он решал с **её/его** помощью.*

Вопрос. Какого рода слово Excel? И следовательно, какого рода должно быть местоимение?

Насколько я помню, род нужно определять исходя из рода родового слова, которое подразумевается. Однако для русскоговорящего человека все английские наименования по звучанию часто походят на существительные определённого рода.

Поэтому в устной речи мы чаще слышим:

— У меня не работает Excel/Word.

— Перезагрузи его [несмотря на женский род слова "программа"].

Другой пример:

— Google не смог ничего найти по нашему запросу [поисковая система Google].

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в текст сообщения вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:

При иноязычных несклоняемых наименованиях промышленных компаний, акционерных обществ, спортивных организаций и подобных обычно применяется принцип согласования с родовым наименованием по отношению к данному слову. Например: «Дженерал электрик» (компания) выплатила акционерам огромные дивиденды; «Тре крунур» (спортивная команда) проиграла нашим хоккеистам оба матча.

Answer (score 0):

"Правило родового слова" не работает там, где речь идёт об устоявшихся заимствованиях, восходящих к именам собственным (ксерокс, факс, дизель, макинтош, френч) либо об именах собственных / названиях марок: бордо, шираз, саке, чанг, "Эксель", "Гугл", мазда, тойота, лимузин, мерседес (исключение - "вольво"), шкода, "Ягуар" и так далее.

Comment: Мне кажется, в вашем случае фигурируют собственные наименования, которые перешли в состав нарицательных, поэтому и пишутся с маленькой буквы.